# could not parse line #126: mongo.database = mongo_db_test

Tags: mongodb, go, revel

I'm following this tutorial [Golang + Revel web framework + Mongodb RESTFul generator for (revel_mgo)](https://medium.com/@kyawmyintthein/revel-mgo-restful-generator-for-revel-web-framework-mongodb-86209de3977e) step by step, but when I finally end it and try to run it, it throw this error

CRIT  16:11:18 revel_container.go:139: Unable to load configuartion file        error="C:\Users\Userx\go\src\RevelApp\conf\app.conf: could not parse line #126:  mongo.database = RevelApp"

The line #126 is like this:

```
[dev]

126 - mongo.database = mongo_db_test
127 - mongo.path = 127.0.0.1:27017
128 - mongo.maxPool = 20
```

Comment: Please show the code that actually produces this error, preferably a [Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, it's hard for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved just putting double quotes like this:

```
 mongo.database = "mongo_db_test"
 mongo.path = "127.0.0.1:27017"
 mongo.maxPool = 20
```